# To convert a String to H256 in Rust

Tags: string, rust

when I get a string like "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", how to convert it to H256 type? I thought there is a simple way like a oneline code.

I found some crate, but can`t find a simply way to solve that.

Comment: Hey, your question lacks some crucial information. E.g. what is a `H256` type? What do you want to achieve, e.g. what's the desired output? Please add them to your question.

Comment: H256 is a web3 type create named ethereum_types .
I'm newer to web3, I don`t know what that means and what to do, there is so little information to search.
I can find the type definition [here](https://docs.rs/ethereum-types/latest/ethereum_types/struct.H256.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Macro [ckb_types::h256](https://docs.rs/ckb-types/0.110.0/ckb_types/macro.h256.html)

Rust :

```rust
use ckb_types::h256;
h256!("0xf8dd02cc2a3174933fac4e87d7f6360c3cc67167db105b28d0bc434a60674e49")
```

cargo.toml:

```
ckb-types = "0.108"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`String.parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse) method.
`String.parse()` can parse into any type that implements the [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/str/traits/trait.FromStr.html) trait, like [`Struct ethers::core::types::H256`](https://docs.rs/ethers-core/latest/ethers_core/types/struct.H256.html).

```rust
use ethers::core::types::H256;

fn main() {
    let a: H256 = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".parse().unwrap();
    //using turbofish syntax.
    let b = "0x1234567890987654321234566535655565653565666656536566565656656560".parse::<H256>().unwrap();

    println!("{}\n{}", a, b);
}
//0x0000…0000
//0x1234…6560
```